# How do I display a custom text-field attribute on the product grid. CE 2.3.2

Tags: custom, custom-attributes, magento2.3.2

Sorry if this is a rehash, but I can't find the exact answer to my problem.

I'm looking to display the contents of a custom text field just under the product name on the category page grid.

I have done the following for another custom attribute in *list.phtml*, and this works:

```
<p><?php echo $_product->getAttributeText('plug_or_plant') ?></p>
```

But it only seems to work on attributes that are dropdown lists.
Does anybody know what changes I have to make to get it to display a text field?

TIA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change the below changes on the admin attribute

Go to the
Stores -> ATTRIBUTES-> Product-> search attribute you want to show like descrption

open the attribute like Description
go to the Storefront Properties  and set "Used in Product Listing"  No To Yes

then after saving the attribute
Please check the attached Image
[image]
clear cache and
reindex

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have done all that already though. I read somewhere that using '$_product->getAttributeText' could be used for dropdowns, but it was something slightly different for text-fields, but I can't find what.

Comment: please use below code for text-field
<p><?php echo $_product->getData('plug_or_plant') ?></p>
or
<p><?php echo $_product->getPlugOrPlant() ?></p>

Comment: Brilliant. That works. Thank you so much.